# Error :One of the values passed to this method or property is incorrect

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, ms-word

I have a word template file with multiply `ContentControl`.

In my website, i want to show this file. I set value for ContentControls.

```
content.Range.Text = field.First().Value;
```

Value is :`Hello \r1\n2\r4\n`. When i set this value i get error :

> One of the values passed to this method or property is incorrect.

I replace value with `Char(11)` & `Char(13)` , it is ok and don't get any errors.

But when i show this file in pdf format with this code.

```
oWordDoc.SaveAs(newXPSDocumentName, WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF);
// Clean up
oWordDoc.Close(WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges);
return File(newXPSDocumentName, "application/pdf");
```

Show `Char(11)` && `Char(13)` Instead of `\n\r`

Comment: hey did you got the solution ??

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```
    public void Test()
    {
        Word.Document doc = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument;
        Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.Text = string.Format("Hello{0}1{1}2{0}4{1}",((char)11).ToString(),((char)13).ToString());
        doc.SaveAs2("Test", Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF);
    }
```

I've used the list that you posted `Hello \r1\n2\r4\n.` which does output an unevenly spaced list.

Comment: Thanks, but `((char)13).ToString()` is `\r` , i get error again

Comment: What is the error that you get, could you post a bit more of your code so I can run it not the code that I've done above?

Comment: I use `content.Range.Text= string.Format("Hello{0}1{1}2{0}4{1}",((char)11).ToString(),((char)13).ToString());` but get error `One of the values passed to this method or property is incorrect`

Comment: Hi I pasted your code directly into Visual Studio and it did come up with an error. I'm not sure whether this is the problem but the code above has some invisible characters between the final two parentheses `))`. If this is actually the problem then try typing the string format into VS not copying and pasting.